# Zipar pasta em PHP apenas com os arquivos

Tags: php, arquivo-zip

Criei uma rotina para criar um arquivo zip de uma pasta em PHP que está funcionando, mas dentro do zip é criada toda a estrutura de pasta existente no servidor e eu não quero que crie assim, gostaria que criasse apenas com os arquivos da pasta.

A função que verifica os arquivo é essa:

```
    $NomesArquivos = array();
    function lista_arquivos($dir) {
    global $NomesArquivos;
        if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
            while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
                if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && is_file($dir.'/'.$file)) {
                    $NomesArquivos[] = $dir.'/'.$file;
                }
            }
            closedir($handle);
        }
        return $NomesArquivos;
    }
    lista_arquivos($caminhopasta);
```

O que eu preciso alterar?

Comment: Descreva melhor o que seria a "estrutura de pastas do servidor", por favor.

Comment: Ele cria o zip com pastas /var/www/[nome-do-site]/wp-content/... e assim até chegar aos arquivos PDF e XML.